# Nested list comprehension equivalent

Tags: python

Is it possible to replace the following code with a list comprehension expression?

```
input = ['1\t2,3\t4,5', '61\t7,8\t9,0']

res = []
li = [i.split() for i in input]
for i in li:
    l = [i[0]]
    l = l + [e.split(',') for e in i[1:]]
    res.append(l)
```

The problem is that the first element in every sublist should be treated differently than the rest of the elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to say this isn't really that Pythonic considering readability.

```
>>> l = ['1\t2,3\t4,5', '61\t7,8\t9,0']
>>> [[i[0]]+[e.split(',') for e in i[1:]] for i in [x.split() for x in l]]
[['1', ['2', '3'], ['4', '5']], ['61', ['7', '8'], ['9', '0']]]
```

Comment: Then what would be a more pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: I meant considering readability. Nothing "un pythonic" about the way you had it either, except maybe I wouldn't have created the intermediary list in your loop.

Comment: You can do `i[:1]` instead of `[i[0]]`

Comment: @Max You could use `csv` like my solution since it is a module built for reading these types of strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> input = ['1\t2,3\t4,5', '61\t7,8\t9,0']
>>> 
>>> [[a.split()[0]] + [b.split(',') for b in a.split()[1:]] for a in input]
[['1', ['2', '3'], ['4', '5']], ['61', ['7', '8'], ['9', '0']]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import csv
>>> data = ['1\t2,3\t4,5', '61\t7,8\t9,0']
>>> [x[:1] + list(csv.reader(x[1:], delimiter=','))
     for x in csv.reader(data, delimiter='\t')]
[['1', ['2', '3'], ['4', '5']], ['61', ['7', '8'], ['9', '0']]]
```