# Python -- list comprehension with try/exception and nested conditional

Tags: python, python-2.7, try-catch, list-comprehension, conditional-statements

This code should find the mode of a list in O(n) linear time.  I want to turn this into a list comprehension because I'm teaching myself Python, and am trying to improve my list comprehension skills.
These were informative but don't really answer my question:

[Convert nested loops and conditions to a list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19346063/convert-nested-loops-and-conditions-to-a-list-comprehension)

[`elif` in list comprehension conditionals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987483/elif-in-list-comprehension-conditionals)

[Nested list comprehension equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598880/nested-list-comprehension-equivalent)

The problem that I'm running into is nesting the if's and the try/except.  I'm sure this is simple question so a junior Python programmer might have the answer quickly.

```
def mode(L):
    # your code here
    d = {}; mode = 0; freq = 0
    for j in L:
        try:
            d[j] += 1
            if d[j] > freq:
                mode = j; freq = d[j]
        except(KeyError): d[j] = 1
    return mode
```

Note that `L` parameter is a list of ints like this:

```
L = [3,4,1,20,102,3,5,67,39,10,1,4,34,1,6,107,99]
```

I was thinking something like:

```
[try (d[j] += 1) if d[j] > freq (mode = j; freq = d[j]) except(KeyError): d[j] = 1 for j in L]
```

But I don't have enough duct tape to fix how badly the syntax is off with that thing.

Comment: `import this`. Read 1-7. Those are the best lessons I learned from Python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know you're learning comprehensions, but you can do this with a default dictionary, or a Counter too.

```
import collections
def mode(L):
    # your code here
    d = collections.defaultdict(lambda: 1); mode = 0; freq = 0
    for j in L:
            d[j] += 1
            if d[j] > freq:
                mode = j; freq = d[j]
    return mode
```

Better still, when you are not trying to learn comprehensions:

```
import collections
def mode(L):
    collections.Counter(L).most_common(1)[0][0]
```

Comment: Counter is the right answer to the problem. DefaultDict is similarly cumbersome. Upvote.

Comment: How to do this with a list comprehension? The accepted answer doesn't reflect the question.

Answer (score 2):

While it might not be possible directly do this within a list comprehension, there's also no reason to. You only really want to be checking for errors when you're actually retrieving the results. As such, you really want to use a `generator` instead of a list comprehension.

Syntax is largely the same, just using parens instead instead of brackets, so you would do something like this:

```
generator = (do something)
try:
    for thing in generator
except KeyError:
   etc...
```

That said, you really don't want to do this for you particular application. You want to use a counter:

```
from collections import Counter
d = Counter(L)
mode = Counter.most_common(1)[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to use `try-except` expressions in list comprenhension.

Quoting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16611498/2670792):

> It is not possible to handle exceptions in a list comprehension for a list comprehension is an expression containing other expression, nothing more (i.e., no statements, and only statements can catch/ignore/handle exceptions).

**Edit 1:**

What you could do instead of using the `try-except` clause, is use the `get` method from the dictionary:

```
def mode(L):
    d = {}
    mode = 0
    freq = 0
    for j in L:
        d[j] = d.get(j, 0) + 1
        if d[j] > freq:
            mode = j
            freq = d[j]
    return mode
```

From [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html):

> **get(key[, default])**: Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. If default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this method never raises a KeyError.

**Edit 2:**

This is my list comprenhension approach, not very efficient, just for fun:

```
r2 = max(zip(L, [L.count(e) for e in L]), key = lambda x: x[1])[0]
```

Comment: I think you want `d[j] = d.get(j, 0) + 1`, with a default of zero rather than one.

Comment: Can you post a list comprehension of your solution?  LC is really what I'm trying to improve skills on, and why I posted originally.

Comment: I don't really know much about list comprenhension, but I cannot think in a way to do this with a list comprenhension (I mean in a similar way of the code you gave). Instead I tried another solution, not the most efficient. See edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can't incorporate `try: except:` in a list comprehension. However, you can get around it by refactoring into a `dict` comprehension:

```
d = {i: L.count(i) for i in L}
```

You can then determine the maximum and corresponding key in a separate test. However, this would be `O(n**2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're trying to find the value that appears most often, an easy way to do that is with `max`:

```
def mode(L):
   return max(L, key=L.count)
```

This is a bit less efficient than the other answers that suggest using `collections.Counter` (it is `O(N^2)` rather than `O(N)`), but for a modest sized list it will probably be fast enough.